# How do I split a string and assign an int value to each of the individual characters of the string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

For example I have a string "Nathan" and I want to split the string into individual characters "N" "A" "T" "H" "A" "N" and after that I also want to match the characters to their corresponding strings. For example "N" would be matched with String N and therefor assigned the value 5, "A" the value 1,...

```
            String A = "1";  String J = "1" ; String S = "1";
            String B = "2";  String K = "2";  String T = "2";
            String C = "3";  String L = "3";  String U = "3";
            String D = "4";  String M = "4";  String V = "4";
            String E = "5";  String N = "5";  String W = "5";
            String F = "6";  String O = "6";  String X = "6";
            String G = "7";  String P = "7";  String Y = "7";
            String H = "8";  String Q = "8";  String Z = "8";
            String I = "9";  String R = "9";

            String firstname = "NATHAN";
```

Comment: Are you asking us for complete code? or did you try to do this and found it difficult? If so, please show what you've tried so that we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have to "assign" some elements to some other elements, Maps are the objects that conceptually best fit this requirement.

```
Map<Character, Integer> mappedValues = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
mappedValues.put('A', 1);
mappedValues.put('B', 2);
...//and so on

String nat = "NATHAN";
Map<Character, Integer> charToInt = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < nat.length(); i++){
    charToInt.put(nat.charAt(i), mappedValues.get(nat.charAt(i)));
}
//{('N', 5), ('A', 1)...}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting the String into char array.

```
String s = "NATHAN";
char[] c = s.toCharArray();
```

Now the individual characters in the array will be indexed starting from 0 like every other array. I just want to demonstrate the following if you are unsure,

```
System.out.println(c[2]); //this will print the character "T"
```

Hope you understood how it works.

Comment: How does this assign an int to every char?

Comment: I added the code after he answered the question, to clarify what i was asking. I am sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: It's the same as the index of an array. There is no explicit assigning of an int to each char. What the code does is, it converts the String s, into a character array c. Now c is the same as all other arrays you have seen in java.

Comment: @NejcFosnaric Now I get what you are asking for. You can use a for loop to iterate through the character array and use an ArrayList which contains a custom object and assign the int that you need.

Comment: create a separate class with 2 variables. one is a char and another is a String. Now list.add(c, s)

Comment: I've heard this can be done using mapping as you have answered, but as I do not know how mapping works, I chose not to say it